# Chart with Dynamic data LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, charts, chartjs

Trying to display the Dynamic data in Pie chart using `Chartjs`, Below is the Code.

To build the chart, how to pass the Dynamic Chart label and Chart data.

This is the response I'm returning from Controller. `{"CS Payroll":40,"Salesforce Implementation":20}`

```
 @track opportunityData = [];
  @wire(aggregateEmployeeProjectHours, { loggedinUserId: "0031I000008Lx44QAC" })
  opptyData({ error, data }) {
    let responsedataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
    let responseErrorJson = JSON.stringify(error);
    console.log("Chart data" + responsedataJson);
    console.log("Chart Error" + responseErrorJson);
    if (data) {
      let oppData = Object.assign({}, data);

      for (let key in oppData) {
        if (oppData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          let tempData = [key, oppData[key]];
          this.opportunityData.push(tempData);
        }
      }
    }
    // alert(this.opportunityData);
    if (error) {
      console.log("Chart errior" + error);
    }
  }
```

**Apex:**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, decimal> aggregateEmployeeProjectHours(Id loggedinUserId){
        Map<String, decimal> timeSheetHoursMap = new Map<String, decimal>();
        for(AggregateResult aggr : [SELECT Sum(emitCS__Hours__c), emitCS__Project__r.Name FROM emitCS__Time_Sheet_Details__c Group by emitCS__Project__r.Name]) {
            timeSheetHoursMap.put((String)(aggr.get('Name')), (decimal)(aggr.get('expr0')));
        }
        system.debug('timeSheetHoursMap' + timeSheetHoursMap);
        return timeSheetHoursMap;
    }
```

```
renderedCallback() {
    // alert("rendered");
    if (!this.chartJSLoaded) {
      // alert("chartJSLoaded" + this.chartJSLoaded);
      loadScript(this, ChartJS)
        .then(() => {
          this.chartJSLoaded = true;

          this.buildChart();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
              title: "Error Loading Chart JS",
              message: error.message,
              variant: "error"
            })
          );           
        });
    }
  }

  buildChart() {
    let canvas = this.template.querySelector("canvas");
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.chart = new window.Chart(context, {
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: [
          "Testing CS",
          "Salesforce Implementation",
          "CRM Implementation",
          "Other project"
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            // label: "# of Votes",
            //data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            data: [20, 45, 32, 52],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)"

            ]

          }
        ]
      },
      options: {

        responsive: true
      }
    });
  }
```

In the Above Build chart for my testing Purpose i have hard coded the values.

Comment: What problem you are facing here?

Comment: Im not sure how to pass type data and number in the build chart method, please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the labels and values in separate arrays from the wired method result. Say `chartLabels` and `chartValues`. Get those filled using wired result data, and then call the `buildChart` function.

```
this.chartLabels = [];
this.chartValues = [];
for (let key in oppData) {
    if (oppData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.chartLabels.push(key);
      this.chartValues.push(oppData[key]);
    }
}
this.buildChart();
```

But before that, you need to make some changes to the `buildChart` function. So it refers to the arrays we created.

```
buildChart() {
    let canvas = this.template.querySelector("canvas");
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.chart = new window.Chart(context, {
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: this.chartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            // label: "# of Votes",
            //data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            data: this.chartValues,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)"

            ]

          }
        ]
      },
      options: {

        responsive: true
      }
    });
 }
```

Optionally you can set the chart colors in the same way.

Comment: this.chartColor = []; this.chartValues.push("rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)"; Like wise we need to create new array and push the color ?

Comment: var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
          this.chartColor.push(bgColor);

Comment: Yes @SFDC_Beginner, you can generate random colors and add them to an array, use refer that array in the chart data.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, It's Working Fine

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner please mark as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider another approach and use this [library](https://github.com/scolladon/lwcc)

This way you would be able to use the reactivity of the library and only deal with the data fetching on your side

```
<c-chart
    type="pie"
    responsive="true"
  >
    <c-dataset
      labels={chartLabels}
    >
      <c-data
        label="# of Votes"
        detail={chartValues}
        backgroundcolor='[
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)"
        ]'
        bordercolor='[
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)"
          ]'
        borderwidth="1"
      ></c-data>
    </c-dataset>
  </c-chart>
```

Where chartValues and chartLabels are tracked property and set by the buildChart method